# Google Map API Error

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

```
  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I'm getting this error type:error:

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value 
 '@integer/google_play_services_version').
```

I imported Google Map and services API into the project I'm also getting `private GoogleMap map;`(GoogleMap red error here)

My Project has Google APIs[Android 4.4] library but I'm still confusing :(

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace this `meta-data` section in you manifest file with this:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="4030500" />
```

Comment: I imported Google APIs but when I create private GoogleMap googlemap it warn me with red error

Comment: Are you sure that the library is imported and you have a green V on it in the properties?

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing an resource in an xml file called integer, which is probably you didn't create, so whether you create this integer.xml and add a resource with the name google_play_services_version or you can replace the `android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"` with `android:value="version of you google play services as a number"`

Comment: I couldnt understand u :(

Comment: it doesn't matter Emil's answer is what i was saying , but i didn't know what will be the number of your google play services

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to the Google play Service.

-- Please Note this answer is based on Eclipse IDE development environment --

+First: import Google_play_service_lip as into your workspace

- I

  - Right click on your Package_Explorer
  - Import
  - Existing Android Code Into Workspace
  - Browse
  - Goto your Android SDK installation folder "Android-sdk"/ or whatever
  - /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
  - Click open
  - (I suggest you to check the box "Copy projects into workspace")
  - Finish

+Second:  Now go to your project that you want to add Google Play Service to it (map in your case)

- II

  - Right click
  - properties
  - on the left-Side Menu select Android
  - On the Right Side part go down to the Library section
  - Click Add
  - Select the library project "google-play-services_lib" // That you imported before.

+Now you can the the two lines to your Manifst files in your application section

```
    <application
...// what ever activities you put here..
>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

+One last point if you still have problems try Clean your project from the Project Menu
Project - Clean